Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln x}{(1+8x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$
Stuck in by parts ( or any other method is appreciated ):
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}
{\left(1 + 8x^{2}\right)\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}\,{\rm d}x
$$

To evaluate this integral, I have tried many different ideas but none seems to get me to any result.
I have tried
$$
x = \sin\left(t\right):\ \mbox{integral of}\quad
\frac{\ln\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{1 + 8 \sin^{2}\left(x\right)},
$$
then by parts taking $\ln\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)$ as first function, but I am getting stuck in
integration by parts of
$$
\cot\left(x\right)\arctan\left(3\tan\left(x\right)\right)
$$
Please help.


Please add your other efforts, or your attempts at doing the integration by parts. Please do so, to prevent downvotes and the potential closure of your question.

Integral of (ln sinx)/(1+ 8 sin²x), then taking ln sinx as first function, but stuck in integral of cotx arctan(3tanx)

I did mean in the question, but I guess that will do :-)

Alternatively took lnx as first function and remaining as second function, still getting an inverse trigo function divided by x.

I doubt if it's elementary: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+ln%28x%29+%2F+%28%281+%2B+8+x%5E2%29+sqrt%281+-+x%5E2%29%29+dx+from+0+to+1

So should I use Simpson's rule and just approximate it?

I might do that, or rewrite the integral before approximating it.

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{(1 + 8 x^2) \sqrt{1 - x^2}}\,dx$$
Put $x=\cos\theta$
$$I=\int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{\ln(\cos\theta)}{1+8\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta$$
Put $t=\tan\theta$
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{8}{{1+t^2}}\right)}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac{-1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+t^2)}{9+t^2}\,dt$$
$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(a^{2}+x^{2})}{b^{2}+x^{2}} \, dx  = \frac{\pi}{b} \,   \ln(a+b)}$$
The above result is from here
Set $a=1,b=3$ in the above formula;
$$I=-\frac{\pi}{3} \,   \ln(2)\approx -0.725$$
Which also agrees with this

Starting with OP’s substitution, $x=\sin \theta$, then
$$
I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln (\sin \theta)}{1+8 \sin ^2 \theta} d \theta
$$
Let $t=\cot \theta$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_{\infty}^0 \frac{\ln \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right)}{1+\frac{t}{1+t^2}} \cdot \frac{-d t}{1+t^2} \\
& =-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+t^2\right)}{9+t^2} d t \\
& =-\frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+t^2\right)}{9+t^2} d t \\
& =-\frac{1}{4}\cdot 2 \Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (t+i)}{9+t^2} d t \\
& =-\frac{1}{4} \cdot 2 \Re\left[2 \pi i \cdot \lim_{t\rightarrow 3i}(t-3 i) \frac{\ln(t+i)}{t^2+9 }\right] \\
& =-\frac{1}{2} \Re\left[2 \pi i \cdot \frac{\ln (4 i)}{6 i}\right] \\
& =-\frac{\pi}{3} \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$

Let $t=\frac{\sqrt {1-x^2}}{x}  $, then $x^2=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{\left(1+8 x^2\right) \sqrt{1-x^2}} d x 
= & \int_{\infty}^0 \frac{\ln \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{8}{1+t^2}\right)\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right)} \cdot\left(-\frac{t}{\left(1+t^2\right)^{\frac 32}}\right) dt\\
= & -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+t^2\right)}{9+t^2} d t \\
= & -\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2 \pi\ln 2}{3} \quad  \text { (as above) } \\
= & -\frac{\pi\ln 2}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{\left(1+8x^2\right) \sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_x^1 \cdots \, dy \, dx = - \int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{dx\,dy}{y\left(1+8x^2\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
&= -\frac13 \int_0^1 \arctan\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{3y} \cdot \frac{dy}y & (*) \\
&= -3 \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan z}{z\left(z^2+9\right)} \, dz & (*) \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \cdots \, dw \, dz = -3 \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{dz\,dw}{\left(z^2+9\right)\left(z^2w^2+1\right)} \\
&= \frac{3\pi}2 \int_0^1 \left(\frac w{1-9w^2} - \frac1{3-27w^2}\right) \, dw \\
&= \frac{3\pi}2 \left(-\frac{\log2}6 - \frac{\log2}{18}\right) = \boxed{-\frac\pi3\log2}
\end{align*}$$
where the integrals labeled $(*)$ are obtained by leveraging an Euler substitution, e.g.
$$\int\frac{dx}{\left(1+8x^2\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}} \stackrel{t=\tfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}=\int\frac{dt}{1+9t^2}=\frac13\arctan(3t)+C$$

Let's make some calculations that will help us out later,
$$J=\int \frac{1}{(1 + 8 x^2) \sqrt{1 - x^2}}\,dx$$
$$= \frac13\int \frac{3}{(1 + 8 x^2) \sqrt{1 - x^2}}\,dx$$
$$=\frac13\int \frac{3(1-x^2)+3x^2}{(1 - x^2+9x^2) \sqrt{1 - x^2}}\,dx$$
$$=\frac13\int \frac{3\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{\left(1 +\frac{9x^2}{1-x^2}\right)({1 - x^2})}\,dx$$
$$=\frac13\int \frac{1}{1 +\left(\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2}\,d\left({\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)$$
$$=\frac13 \arctan \left(\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$


$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)}{(1 + 8 x^2) \sqrt{1 - x^2}}\,dx=-\frac13\int_0^1 \frac1x \arctan \left(\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right) \,dx$$

Coming back to $I$, After Integrating by parts, we get,
$$I=-\frac13\int_0^1 \frac1x \arctan \left(\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right) \,dx$$
Consider, $$I(a)=-\frac13\int_0^1 \frac1x \arctan \left(\frac{3ax}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right) \,dx$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}I(a)=-\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2+9a^2x^2}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{9a^2-1}\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1-9a^2)}{1-x^2+9a^2x^2}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{9a^2-1}\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x^2+9a^2x^2)-9a^2}{(1-x^2+9a^2 x^2)(\sqrt{1-x^2})}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{9a^2-1}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx+\frac{1}{1-9a^2}\int_0^1 \frac{9a^2}{(1-x^2+9a^2 x^2)(\sqrt{1-x^2})}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2(9a^2-1)}+\frac{1}{1-9a^2}\int_0^1 \frac{9a^2}{(1-x^2+9a^2 x^2)(\sqrt{1-x^2})}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2(9a^2-1)}+\frac{1}{1-9a^2}\int_0^1 \frac{9a^2+9a^2x^2-9a^2x^2}{(1-x^2)\left(1+\frac{9a^2 x^2}{1-x^2}\right)(\sqrt{1-x^2})}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2(9a^2-1)}+\frac{1}{1-9a^2}\int_0^1 \frac{9a^2(1-x^2)+9a^2x^2}{(1-x^2)\left(1+\frac{9a^2 x^2}{1-x^2}\right)(\sqrt{1-x^2})}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2(9a^2-1)}+\frac{1}{1-9a^2}\int_0^1 \frac{9a^2\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{9a^2x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{(1-x^2)\left(1+\left(\frac{3ax}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2\right)}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2(9a^2-1)}+\frac{3a}{1-9a^2}\int_0^1 \frac{3a\sqrt{1-x^2}+(2x)(3ax)\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{3ax}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2(9a^2-1)}+\frac{3a}{1-9a^2}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{3ax}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2}\,d\left(\frac{3ax}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right)$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2(9a^2-1)}+\frac{3a\pi}{2(1-9a^2)}=\frac{(3a-1)\pi}{2(1-9a^2)}$$
$$\int_0^1 dI(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1\frac{(3a-1)}{1-9a^2}\,da$$
$$I(1)\underset{I(0)=0}=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1\frac{(3a-1)}{(1-9a^2)}\,da=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1\frac{(3a-1)}{(9a^2-1)}\,da$$
$$I(1)=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{3a+1}\,da=-\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2)$$
Therefore,
$$\color{red}{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)}{(1 + 8 x^2) \sqrt{1 - x^2}}\,dx=-\frac{\pi}{3}\ln(2)}$$
